# return json as key pair format with asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

i write a project with asp.net and jquery.in part of web page i have:

```
  <div id="lookup">
                        <div class="other">
                            <div class="st"></div>
                            <ul class="videos"></ul>
                            <ul class="items"></ul>
```

in web service i write this code to get search keyword and search in videos and products collections and return it to web page.part of web service is :

```
 public string GetSearchResult(string keyword, string urlCode)
{
string test = [sample code];
string test2 = [sample code2];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(test2);
return @"[
            {
                ""Key"": ""video"",
                ""Value"": {
                    ""m_MaxCapacity"": " + sb.MaxCapacity + @",
                    ""Capacity"": " + sb.Capacity + @",
                    ""m_StringValue"": """ + test + @""",
                    ""m_currentThread"": 0
                }
            },
            {
                ""Key"": ""product"",
                ""Value"": {
                    ""m_MaxCapacity"": " + sb2.MaxCapacity + @",
                    ""Capacity"": " + sb2.Capacity + @",
                    ""m_StringValue"": """ + test2 + @""",
                    ""m_currentThread"": 0
                }
            }]";

}
```

in jquery , part of code is :

```
function lookUp() {

    n = $("#SearchBox").val().trim(),
    r = "All";
    n.length >= 2 ? ($.ajax({
    url: ServiceUrl + "SearchService.asmx/GetSearchResult",
    data: '{keyword: "' + n + '",urlCode:"' + r + '" }',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 15000,
    processData: !1,
    success: function (o) {
        o != null && (r == "All" ? (f.show(), u.show().html(o[2].Value.m_StringValue), .........
```

this code must get search results in video category or product category from web service and fill video or items ul in web page with sample code or sample code2.
this code it does not work . i want to determine each m_StringValue. i know returned from web service should not be text and i want to be as :

```
 [{"Key":"video","Value":  {"m_MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Capacity":64,"m_StringValue":"sample   code","m_currentThread":0}},
 {"Key":"product","Value":  {"m_MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Capacity":55,"m_StringValue":"sample code    2","m_currentThread":0}}]
```

but i don't know how to change web service.

Comment: try this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/775153/Asp-net-Web-service-return-json-format-data

Comment: thanks, but can you explain more? your link does not like with my question.i want to define key,value ,capacity,maxcapacity.

Comment: It depends on where do you want to determine it, in Jacascript or where?

Comment: i want to determine maxcapacity,capacity,... in asp.net web service.

Comment: Why do you want to return your JSON in this complicated format?  Why not something like `{"video":"sample code","product":"sample code 2"}` for a single result or `[{"video":"sample code","product":"sample code 2"}]` for multiple results?  Also, are you asking us how to write the webservice code in c#, or the jquery code in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to deserialize the JSON to a .Net type. You can use JavascriptSerializer. First create classes that have the field names and types that are present in your JSON, then deserialize into that type. Example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace loopy
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      string websvcResult = CallWebService();
      var keysAndCapacities = ser.Deserialize<List<ServiceResultClass>>(websvcResult);
    }

    public static string CallWebService()
    {
      //Call web service here, this is just a mock of course.
      return @"[
                {
                    ""Key"": ""products"",
                    ""Value"": {
                        ""m_MaxCapacity"": 2147483647,
                        ""Capacity"": 64,
                        ""m_StringValue"": ""<li>sample products or search results in products category</li>"",
                        ""m_currentThread"": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    ""Key"": ""news"",
                    ""Value"": {
                        ""m_MaxCapacity"": 2147483647,
                        ""Capacity"": 55,
                        ""m_StringValue"": ""<li class='noresult'>sample news or search results in news category</li>"",
                        ""m_currentThread"": 0
                    }
                }
            ]";
    }
  }

  public class ServiceResultClass
  {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Capacities Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class Capacities
  {
    public long m_MaxCapacity { get; set; }
    public string m_StringValue { get; set; }
  }
}
```

If you break at the end of Main() and inspect keysAndCapacities, you get this:

[image]